# Java how to iterate all values of HashMap in Parallel

Tags: java, java-8, parallel-processing, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `HashMap` with Key of type `HashSet` and Value of type `ArrayList`.

Once all the key-value values pairs are inserted to `Map`. I want to iterate each key and its value for further process, not just print, it will be used in the further process where Key and values are passed as String parameters.

So I was thinking if at all this is possible, like instead of iterating each key-value one at a time in Map i.e. waiting for the First iteration to get over for the complete process, only then next iteration starts. Instead, if it's possible to iterate all key values in parallel without having to wait for its turn then the overall result will be faster. The order of iteration is not important. It should just read all key-value pairs in parallel.

I tried Stream API but that is only printing all iterations value in parallel but in the further process, it's not doing what I am expecting maybe I am doing something wrong as I am not familiar with Streams. In case if this can't be achieved with available inbuilt functions or classes then even third party Jars (Apache-commons) will do.

This is code which I have tried so far:

```
String jobId = "J1";
Map<Set<String>,List<String>> map_batch_result_details = new HashMap<Set<String>,List<String>>();
Set<String> hs_batchesId= new HashSet<String>();
List<String> list_resultId = new ArrayList<String>();

hs_batchesId.add("B1"); 
hs_batchesId.add("B2"); 
hs_batchesId.add("B3");

list_resultId.add("R1");
list_resultId.add("R2");
list_resultId.add("R3");


map_batch_result_details.put(hs_batchesId, list_resultId); 

map_batch_result_details.entrySet().stream().forEach(e -> {
System.out.format("key: %s, value: %s%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue());  // for printing results using stream without iterating each row sequentially instead iterates it parallely

 InputStream inputStream =  Connection.getQueryResultStream(jobId, e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue().toString());
/*
getQueryResultStream expects one batchId which is  <Key> of Map but it needs it in String so I am using toString
similarly third parameter expects one resultId which is <value> of Map again in String so toString
But Code fails as it is not passing 1 key and 1 value, rather it passes all key values at once in single call.
*/

});
```

**Output**

```
CALL: getQueryResultStream(jobId, e.getKey().toString(),e.getValue().toString());

**Actual values passed**
 getQueryResultStream(J1,[B1,B2,B3],[R1,R2,R3])

**Expected values**
getQueryResultStream(J1,B1,R1)
getQueryResultStream(J1,B2,R2)
getQueryResultStream(J1,B3,R3)

Expected value should execute in Parallel without having to wait for first iteration to get over. But not in one call which is happening in Actual values.
```

Comment: Did you try `map_batch_result_details.entrySet().parallelStream()` instead of `map_batch_result_details.entrySet().stream()`?

Comment: @mexicomanni Even with parallelStream() its still passing all Keys and values of Map in method getQueryResultStream(jobId, e.getKey().toString(), e.getValue().toString() not matching with expected result. Please check my post I have added actual and expected result.

Comment: you only have one key-value pair in your HashMap, so it can not process anything parallely.

Comment: @mexicomanni my bad. thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a `HashMap` with Key of type `HashSet` and Value of type `ArrayList`.

This is the problem. The only one entry regardless what is inside the key/value. Moreover, this structure doesn't guarantee that `"B1"` and `"R1"` are bound together as long as the `HashSet` is unordered.

I recommend using the way different structure. You used a `Map` with only one entry having both key and value as a collection, which is impractical for simultaneous iteration.

I recommend using a list of either a custom or any imported class `Pair<T, R>` (with getter methods say `first` and `second`) or `Entry<K, V>` that works in the same way:

```
List<Entry<String, String>> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new SimpleEntry<>("B1", "R1"));
entries.add(new SimpleEntry<>("B2", "R2"));
entries.add(new SimpleEntry<>("B3", "R3"));

entries.parallelStream()
       .forEach(e -> System.out.format("key: %s, value: %s%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
```

As long as the Stream is parallel, the `forEach` output is unordered and appears random. A sample output:

> ```
> key: B2, value: R2
> key: B1, value: R1
> key: B3, value: R3
> ```

By the way, you might want to continue the streaming instead of using `forEach`:

```
entries.parallelStream()
       .map(e-> Connection.getQueryResultStream(jobId, e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
       ...
```

---

Edit: If the input is `Map<Set<String>, List<String>>` and you cannot change it, you convert it to `List<Entry<String, String>>` using the following snippet. The only hope is that `Set` is `LinkedHashSet` that maintains order and the linkage between key and value will be kept as intented:

```
map_batch_result_details.forEach((k, v) -> {
    Iterator<String> keysIterator = k.iterator();
    Iterator<String> valuesIterator = v.iterator();
    while (keysIterator.hasNext() && valuesIterator.hasNext()) {
        String key = keysIterator.next();
        String value = valuesIterator.next();
        entries.add(new SimpleEntry<>(key, value));
        }
    }
);
```